# Keep showing prompt, until correct value is given in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to show the prompt everytime, the user gives a null or incorrect input. Only upon, giving the correct entry, will the prompt go and an alert will be shown. This is my code:

```
var pass=prompt("Please enter the password to view your recovery code.");
while(true){
    if(pass=="abc"){
        break;
    }
    else
       var pass=prompt("Please enter the password to view your recovery code."); 
}

alert("correct");
```

Now, even if I give the correct value (`abc`), the prompt still remains and the `alert` never shows. Why?

Comment: remove the 2nd `var` in front of the variable name

Comment: Doesn't work. The prompt still keeps on showing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was because you had re-define the variable `pass` with the line `var pass=prompt(...)`

You should also consider using `let` instead of `var`

Also, i've updated the condition do make something a little bit cleaner

```js
let pass = prompt("Please enter the password to view your recovery code.");
while(pass !== "abc"){
       pass = prompt("Please enter the password to view your recovery code."); 
}

alert("correct");
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be simpler than that. Add the prompt inside the loop, and break if the password is a match.

```js
while (true) {

  const pass = prompt('Please enter the password to view your recovery code.');
  
  if (pass === 'abc') {
    console.log('Correct!');
    break;
  }

}
```